# Expression<Func<PartJoinTable, bool>> predicate=null; throws error in where condition(query.Where(predicate))

Tags: c#, linq

```
 Expression<Func<PartJoinTable, bool>> predicate = null;

 var query2 = query.Join(partJoinTableRepository.GetPartJoinQuery(),
                         "x.PartID", "PartID", "inner" + row + "", null);
 foreach (var item1 in query)
 {
     list.Add(new PartJoinTable
     {
          ProductTypeId = item1.x.ProductTypeId,
          PartId = item1.x.PartId
     });

  }
  predicate = PredicateBuilder.True(list.AsQueryable());


  if (typeid=="3")
  {
      if (row == 0)
      {
          predicate1 = predicate1.And(z => cpaclassids.Contains(z.x.ProductTypeId.ToString()));
      }
      else
      {
          predicate = predicate.And(x => cpaclassids.Contains(x.ProductTypeId.ToString()));
       }
    }
    row++;
}
int lst1 = query.Where(predicate).Select(x => x).Distinct().ToList().Count();
```

> Cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>' to 'System.Func<, bool>'

I am not able to retrieve results as it shows the above error when I declare the variable `Expression<Func<PartJoinTable, bool>> predicate = null;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for

> Expression> predicate=null; throws error in
>   where condition(query.Where(predicate))

is

```
if (predicate != null)
    query = query.Where(predicate);

int lst1 = query.Distinct().Count();
```

Add `where` clause only when it exists. Using `.ToList()` before `.Count()` you are projecting every row from database to memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can write with `?` - and it saves questions like: `if (predicate != null)`

This is the Full code:

```
int lst1 = query.Where(predicate)?.Select(x => x)?.Distinct()?.ToList()?.Count;
```

You can write only: `Count` - property in class `List`